# How do I write a query that works in both HSQLDB and MySQL to add days to a date in the WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, where-clause, hsqldb

I'd like to add a specific number of days to a date column and then compare that to the current date. Is there any way I can achieve this that is compatible with both HSQLDB (for testing) and MySQL (production)?

To make things even more complicated, I am using Hibernate.

Comment: mysql: `WHERE somefield + INTERVAL 42 day > curdate()`. as for a query that works in both, doubt it. sql maybe a "standard" language, but it's basically british sql v.s. american sql v.s. australian sql. tons of dialects that all do stuff slightly differently.

Comment: Unfortuantely, it appears that interval syntax does not work in hibernate, which is a bummer.

Comment: HSQLDB: `WHERE somefield + INTERVAL 42 day > curdate()` and several alternatives to curdate() all work.

Comment: fredt: yep. The solution was just to not use hibernate. Hibernate doesn't support intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the background of your problem, but can you do it the other way around: compare dae column with current date substracted by number of days?

I meant something like this in hql (I'm using jpql in this example, if you prefer JPA interface):

```
TypedQuery<SomeClass> q = getEntityManager().crateQuery(
    "select s from SomeClass s where s.date = :date", SomeClass.class);
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
// subtract number of days from current date, e.g. 10 days
now.add(Calendar.DAY, -10);
q.setParameter("date", now);
List<SomeClass> = q.getResultList();
```

This approach is database-agnostic, but of course works only for trivial cases, in some mor e complicated cases it will not work.

Comment: The problem is that functions that subtract or add from a date operate different in hsql compared to mysql. The interval syntax works in both hsql and mysql, but then it doesn't work in hql (hibernate query language). My solution was to suffer writing all of the queries in regular SQL. It was just a mild pain in the butt to rewrite them, but it worked.